# JxBrowser Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, chromium, jxbrowser

I have been stuck on the same issue for a few days now, and I am starting to wonder if it is due to the support that JxBrowser offers. I am trying to implement a BFS graph for visualisation purposes using a Cytoscape.js library. Does JxBrowser offer compatibility for external Javascript libraries, or is it limited to a few? I see in the documentation that it specifically talks about JQuery support, but nothing else. I have tried to implement my cytoscape library in the same manner as the JQuery tutorial given by JxBrowser, but it comes up as being undefined.

Code is below:
    package src.java;

```
public class VisualFrame {

public VisualFrame(final Browser browser, final BrowserView view, final JFrame frame){
    frame.setTitle("Visualisation");
    frame.setResizable(false);

    InputStream urlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("../web/cytoscape/index.html");
    String html = null;
    try (BufferedReader urlReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (urlStream))) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String row;
        while ((row = urlReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(row);
        }
        html = builder.toString(); 
    }  catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    final String loadHelloPath = html;





    browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent event) {
            System.out.println(browser.getHTML());
            if (event.isMainFrame()) {
                System.out.println("Has Reached");
                event.getBrowser().executeJavaScript("var cy = cytoscape({"
                        + "style: cytoscape.stylesheet()"
                        + ".selector('node')"
                        + ".css({"
                        + "'content': 'data(id)'})"
                        + ".selector('edge')"
                        + ".css({"
                        + "'curve-style': 'bezier',"
                        + "'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',"
                        + "'width': 4,"
                        + "'line-color': '#ddd',"
                        + "'target-arrow-color': '#ddd'})"
                        + ".selector('.highlighted')"
                        + ".css({"
                        + "'background-color': '#61bffc',"
                        + "'line-color': '#61bffc',"
                        + "'target-arrow-color': '#61bffc',"
                        + "'transition-property': 'background-color, line-color, target-arrow-color',"
                        + "'transition-duration': '0.5s'}),"
                        + "container: document.getElementById('cy'),"
                        + "elements: {"
                        + "nodes: ["
                        + "{ data: { id: 'a' } },"
                        + "{ data: { id: 'b' } },"
                        + "{ data: { id: 'c' } },"
                        + "{ data: { id: 'd' } },"
                        + "{ data: { id: 'e' } }],"
                        + "edges: ["
                        + "{ data: { id: 'ae', weight: 1, source: 'a', target: 'b' } },"
                        + "{ data: { id: 'ab', weight: 1, source: 'a', target: 'c' } },"
                        + "{ data: { id: 'be', weight: 1, source: 'b', target: 'd' } },"
                        + "{ data: { id: 'bc', weight: 1, source: 'b', target: 'e' } },"
                        + "{ data: { id: 'ce', weight: 1, source: 'c', target: 'f' } }]}"
                        + "});");
            }
        }
    });

    browser.loadHTML(loadHelloPath);


}
}
```

I have script type="text/javascript" src="cytoscape.js"> in the head of my HTML file as well, so I assume it would import the external library which is in the same file path as the index file itself.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Index.html I am aiming to use:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Visualisation</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cytoscape.js"></script>
  </head>

  <style>
    #cy {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
  }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div id="cy"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks, Jack

Comment: have you checked your js code for any errors?

Comment: @ManosKounelakis I have added a ConsoleListener and the error message I get is: event.getMessage() = Uncaught ReferenceError: cytoscape is not defined. This makes me think it can't even get by the first line of my JS code where I assign cy to cytoscape??

Comment: can you post cytoscape code?

Comment: Edited now, the actual Cytoscape library is over 30,000+ lines of code, but the script I am aiming to use is now above! Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked that in your html file you include the cytoscape library?
Cause it seems like you have forgotten to iclude it

Comment: @ManosKounelakis I've edited the original post to include my full HTML file. I believe this is the correct way to include the cytoscape.js library (as a script in the header)? I have ran my index.html file in a separate folder with my cytoscape files in the same directory and it works fine. I assume JxBrowser is the reason this isn't working, maybe the loadHTML operation?

Comment: @JackOnslow Could you please open the index.html in Google Chrome and then try executing your JavaScript code in the console?
If it works properly on Google Chrome, please try loading the index.html in JxBrowser without parsing it to HTML string, e.g. browser.loadUrl("full_path_to_index.html");

Comment: @NikitaShvinagir I was thinking that may be the issue, and it was! I don't fully understand the difference between loadHTML and loadURL and the reason why I don't have to invokeAndWaitToLoad everytime, but for the time being I am good to go, thank you!